# Container with drop shadow containing a dynamic GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So a design requires **Containing** a GridView of profiles that is dynamic in size.

[image]

The one I came up with is something like this:

```
class Applicants extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: GridView.builder(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              itemCount: 10,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildBox(context, index),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

But how do I put them in a **Container** with a drop shadow that extends with GridView? This list is populated from DB and my attempts of placing the GridView in a Container with DropShadow always fail.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is using `Card` and use `elevation`.

```dart
 Widget _buildBox(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 12,
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Applicant"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: sorry not creating a dropshadow on each items but the Container that contains all of them

Comment: you can wrap with another Card on gridView parent widget.